# Django: Using get_form_kwarg to pass url pramater into form __init__ for ModelChoiceField selection filiter

Tags: python, django

I am building a FAQ app.

Model flow Topic -> Section -> Article.

Article has a FK to Section which has a FK to Topic.

In my create article from I want to take in the Topic_Pk so when the user selects a Section the choice selection is limited to just the Sections attached under the Topic.

I am using get_from_kwarg to pass the Topic_Pk from the url to `__init__` in the form. I keep getting a `TypeError __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'topic_pk'`. I do not want to pop the data or set topic_pk=None in the `__init__` parameters as this would invalidate the whole point.

What is it I am missing to allow me to use this variable?

Url:

```
url(r'^ironfaq/(?P<topic_pk>\d+)/article/create$', ArticleCreateView.as_view()),
```

View:

```
class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    form_class = CreateArticleForm
    template_name = "faq/form_create.html"
    success_url = "/ironfaq"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ArticleCreateView,self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(self.kwargs)
        return kwargs
```

Form:

```
class CreateArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    section = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Section.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['section'].queryset = Section.objects.filter(topic_pk=self.kwargs['topic_pk'])

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        widgets = {
            'answer': forms.Textarea(attrs={'data-provide': 'markdown', 'data-iconlibrary': 'fa'}),
        }
        fields = ('title','section','answer')
```

Model:

```
class Article(Audit):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sort = models.SmallIntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.TextField()
    vote_up = models.IntegerField()
    vote_down = models.IntegerField()
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "articles"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def total_votes(self):
        return self.vote_up + self.vote_down

    def percent_yes(self):
        return (float(self.vote_up) / self.total_votes()) * 100

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('faq-article-detail',(), {'topic__slug': self.section.topic.slug,
            'section__slug': self.section.slug, 'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: I missed the point, why don't you want to pop `topic_pk`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your current `__init__` signature, you **must** pop `topic_pk` from kwargs before you call `super()`, otherwise you'll get the `TypeError`.

In your question, you say that popping the value would 'invalidate the whole point', but I think you're mistaken. You can still use the `topic_pk` value after calling `super()`.

```
class CreateArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    section = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Section.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        topic_pk = kwargs.pop('topic_pk')
        super(CreateArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['section'].queryset = Section.objects.filter(topic_pk=topic_pk)
```

Another approach would be to use `topic_pk` as a named argument. Note that this changes the signature of the `__init__` method, so it might break other code (for example if you had `CreateArticleForm(request.POST)` somewhere else).

```
    def __init__(self, topic_pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['section'].queryset = Section.objects.filter(topic_pk=topic_pk)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. I did not realize that when I was using pop the code was hanging up on the filter.